# Is there a way to export call log of a Nokia 130?

Tags: export, nokia-pc-suite, symbian, nokia-ovi-suite

I have search high and low to get a way to export the call log from a Nokia 130. I have had one but lost it before I could try the Nokia suites on it. I need to know the export ability before buy it again or I have to buy another model. Please help.

Comment: Just use the log your provider likely provides?

Comment: It's not always available, especially with prepaid plan.

Comment: Might be dependent on your country. I'm pretty sure it's always available here (you need to be able to check whenever they're charging you correctly), though there might sometimes be some additional cost attached if they should mail you that log. Did you check whenever it's available for you? That Nokia seems to be rather cheap, any reason you would not just get one and try it? Why are you interested in getting the call log anyway? Maybe there's a better solution available?

Comment: The phone will be used for marketing purpose. So I need the log to summarize the result of the campaign.

Comment: At the end, I just buy an android phone. There are a few apps capable of extracting call log.