# Export call history from Nokia (Symbian) phone

Tags: mobile-phone, nokia-pc-suite, symbian, nokia-ovi-suite

I have a Nokia 3500c phone from which I would like to export the history (log) of calls.

With Nokia Suite I can export everything (contacts, SMS messages, files) but call history:

[image]

Is there any [geeky] way to fish the list of calls out? I can browse it on the phone and so far I see only two clumsy options: 1) Manually type them down like a monkey; 2) Request call history from the cell provider.

([This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1285662/is-there-a-way-to-export-call-log-of-a-nokia-130) might be regarded as duplicate but it does not dig this deep.)

Comment: Can you not login to your 'phone account and see your call log there? I am on Vodafone in the UK and all my call history is available online.

Comment: @spikey_richie My mobile provider only allows to export the last 3 months. For longer periods I would have to visit their office. Too much of a trouble given that all I want is here in the phone in my hands. Just need to fish it out.

Comment: If you use 'Back Up', what does that output? From memory, you get a single file with everything in which the Nokia PC Suite can read back. And from memory, you can edit that file in Notepad++ and the content is essentially CSV for things like Contacts and Messages.

Comment: @spikey_richie "Back up" yields an *.nbu file (binary). I can browse it with NbuExplorer and again, there is everything but call history.

Comment: Dang, that's pretty annoying.